# Get data from a local API with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have local api at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
I want to receive data from my api http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/
I've already received the response object in the console, but I can not move on.

My code:

```
export function fetchBooksWithRedux() {
   return dispatch => {
      dispatch(fetchBooksBegin());
      return fetchBooks().then(([response, json]) =>{
         if(response.status === 200){
            dispatch(fetchBooksSuccess(json))
         }
         else{
             dispatch(fetchBooksError())
         }
      })
   };
}

function fetchBooks() {
    return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/")
    .then( response => console.log("1", response.data, typeof response))
    .then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}

export const fetchBooksSuccess = books => ({
    type: 'FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS',
    payload: { books }
});
```

> in console: 1 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] object
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

**I will be grateful for any tips**

Comment: What's going on `handleErrors`?

Comment: The code is parsed on the basis of an example from the Internet, I understand this is some kind of error handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` doesn't have a return value, so the next `then` will get `undefined` passed in as the `response` argument.

```js
// response = Response(...)
.then( response => console.log("1", response.data, typeof response)) 
// response = undefined
.then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
```

If you want to tap into a then chain to log, you must also return the input.

```js
.then( response => { 
  console.log("1", response.data, typeof response); 
  return response;
})
.then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
```